# How to downcast / cast a struct's generic type in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've refactored my work with UICollectionViewCells into the following

```
struct CollectionViewCellModel<T: UICollectionViewCell> {
    let reuseIdentifier: NSString
    let allowsSelection: Bool

    // Optional callbacks
    var onCreate: ((T) -> Void)?            = nil
    var onSelection: ((T) -> Void)?         = nil
    var onWillBeDisplayed: ((T) -> Void)?   = nil
    var onDelete: ((T) -> Void)?            = nil

    // Create cell
    func toCell(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> T {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as T
        if let onCreate = onCreate { onCreate(cell) }
        return cell
    }
}
```

This has made it easier for me to create a list of specific cells (For things like forms) and then work with them.

However, I keep getting tripped up in how to store these objects. I can't downcast them to `CollectionViewCellModel<UICollectionViewCell>` and therefore can't store a list of `[CollectionViewCellModel<UICollectionViewCell>`

I thought Swift supported down-casting, but apparently not for generic types?

```
let cell = CollectionViewCellModel<A>(...)
let genericCell = cell as CollectionViewCellModel<UICollectionViewCell>
// ERROR: UICollectionViewCell is not identical to A
let genericMaybeCell = cell as? CollectionViewCellModel<UICollectionViewCell>
// ERROR: UICollectionViewCell is not identical to A
```

Do I have to store these as an array of `Any` and then cast them every time or am I just misunderstanding something (or both)?

---

Update: I've done some work in the playground to clearly illustrate what I mean:

```
protocol IA {
    func name() -> String
}

class A:IA { func name() -> String { return "A (Base)" } }
class B: A { override func name() -> String { return "B (Child of A)" } }
class C: B { override func name() -> String { return "C (Child of B)" } }

struct SA<T: A> {
}

let struct0: Any = SA<B>()
// OK: yes, the struct of B is an Any! 
// but since B inherits from A, isn't it safe to 
// say that SA<B> is also of type SA<A>?
let struct1: SA<A> = SA<B>() as SA<A>
// NO
// ERROR: 'B' is not identical to 'A'
let struct1Optional: SA<A> = SA<B>() as? SA<A>
// not even optionally? NO
// ERROR: 'B' is not identical to 'A'
```

I guess it's not possible. Maybe in Swift 1.3. See thread in comments.

Update (2/17/15)

---

For those of you interested in why I'm even doing this in the first place, you have to understand how I'm working with my CollectionViewControllers (CVCs). I've abstracted a base CVC to perform the common methods every screen needs. This CVC has a protocol that expects a `Factory` that creates CVC models. These models know how to transform themselves, respond to actions, and very much act like a controller. They're fat & active. My views on the other hand are all dumb. All they know how to do is move stuff around on the screen or go into different display states. When configuring a cell from a CVC, you end up doing these big switch statements that really don't tell you much from a readability perspective expect "route this". It gets worse you start to configure your view in there. It's not horrible, but generally speaking -- to me -- a view controller controls the *view* it's responsible for. While this VC might be the parent VC of the cell, this does not give it proper access to manipulate it heavily. This now makes your VC do things like `cell.changeDisplayToActiveState()`; in short, it now bears the burden of controlling its children cells. This is what contributes to all the "fat" VCs out there. I first chose to deviate from this path by adopting the `VIPER` pattern, but I found it overkill -- especially for a new project. I scrapped it and began to work with a base CVC. This is currently how my project works:

- A base CVC expects a factory & factory expects a CVC (thus facilitating two way binding for the cells)
- This factory produces cell & header models **for THE CVC**.
- These models have callback & data & configuration functionality embedded within them.
- They can call PUBLIC functions of the view controller from these callbacks (thus strictly separating responsibilities) such as `vc.changeDisplayState(...)` or `changeToVc(...)`

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? Is it 1.2? And why do you even need Generic for this? Using `UICollectionViewCell` directly should be just fine I think. And what's the type of `A`?

Comment: The bottom line is that `CollectionViewCellModel<MyCollectionViewCell>` and `CollectionViewCellModel<UICollectionViewCell>` are completely unrelated and noninterchangeable types.  Your best bet is probably to make this a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and inherit all your custom cells from that.

Comment: There's a thread on this kind of downcasting in the dev forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/261699?tstart=30

Comment: The usage of abstracting the collection VIEW's DATA as a MODEL has many advantages @sikhapol. a uniform protocol and simple interface being a couple. it also makes unit testing easier. will this cell data model create a cell with these fields filled in? I personally believe in stuffing in a lot of related data together and then wrapping it up nice and neat. a class kingdom certainly needs identified domains, doesn't it? I have a simple collection of these models to work witih in the VC. A factory generates them and the VC don't care about that. thanks Nate I guess it's not possible yet

Comment: @joslinm Yes, I see the use for bundling cell and data in that way. But my point was, why did you need to use generic. By having a concrete type constraint (`UICollectionViewCell` in this case), you don't get much abstraction out of generic more than the old-school polymorphism. Your generic struct still depend on it. The only benefit I can see is that you won't need to do explicit down casting in those closures if you declare it with your subclass's type. But it won't help you much in the case above, since you have more than two subclasses. There'll be down casting somewhere anyway.

Comment: There's something that doesn't feel right about that approach. Separating out the data model for the collectionview allows me all the possibilities that comes with owning any set of objects. I could cache them, implement properties, create a factory or model transformer that makes them. A collection VC that expects these cell-view-models is a lot more versatile in my opinion. could you do the same with the cells? not really. cells are owned by the collectionview and are subject to cache changes. relying on them as models of the data you're displaying is dangerous; they should be dumb.

Comment: Any solution for this? I am running into exactly the same issue - have created a class representing a property on a model entity - it uses generics for representing the value type and now I've found that downcasting is not possible... Which makes all the work I've done useless. This is very disappointing and frustrating. One workaround is to have a base class that does not use generics and cast to it, but that's useless to me since I'm not able to extract the generics info from that...

Comment: Sorry Charlie, there's no real solution until 1.3 (and who even knows if that will fix it). As I said in the dev forums thread above, "Since you can't do this, I treat them as `Any` objects and then cast them to their expected type. Not horrible, but certainly not ideal." Also see the answer I accepted -- it's the closest we'll get for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but I'll try to answer.  Presumably you are not interested in storing a bunch of `CollectionViewCellModel<X>`'s  for some specific `X`, because then the answer to "how do I store them?" would be simple: `[CollectionViewCellModel<X>]`.  So I'm guessing you want a you want an array of `CollectionViewCellModel<T>` for heterogeneous `T`'s.  The best way to achieve that is to give all your `CollectionViewCellModel<T>`'s a common protocol (or base class, but in your case they're `struct`s, so not that), something roughly like this:

```
protocol CollectionViewCellModelType {
  var reuseIdentifier: NSString {get}
  var allowsSelection: Bool {get}

  func toCell(
    collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: NSIndexPath
  ) -> UICollectionViewCell
}

struct CollectionViewCellModel<T: UICollectionViewCell>
  : CollectionViewCellModelType {
  let reuseIdentifier: NSString
  let allowsSelection: Bool

  // Optional callbacks
  var onCreate: ((T) -> Void)?            = nil
  var onSelection: ((T) -> Void)?         = nil
  var onWillBeDisplayed: ((T) -> Void)?   = nil
  var onDelete: ((T) -> Void)?            = nil

  // Create cell
  func toCell(
    collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: NSIndexPath
  ) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
      reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! T

    if let onCreate = onCreate { onCreate(cell) }
    return cell
  }
}

var a: [CollectionViewCellModelType] = [] // put them in here
```

Hoping this helps,

Dave

Comment: Spot on. I want a heterogeneous collection of cell models. For example `EditTextFieldCVModel<EditTextFieldCVCell>`; the model thus becomes responsible for holding onto the necessary data and configuring the view. The same general approach holds for onSelect and all that. All delegate methods become one liners where all the relevant actions (data, config, callbacks, etc) is found in CVModel. Ty!

Comment: In my case, I was able to get away with using `enum` with associated values instead. Had the same result.